# Microsoft Graph API to retrieve License / Plan Information

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, licensing

Microsoft Office 365 has various plans like E3, E5, Microsoft 365 etc. Is there any API to get the details of their License / Plan. There are APIs to retrieve license details of the particular user but there is no API available at organizational level.

Comment: Have you checked this [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get)? See if this helps.

Comment: Yes. Organization API will give all provisioned plans / services. The API subscribedSkus will give you the subscribed SKUs and license information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [List subscribedSkus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the list of commercial subscriptions that an organization has acquired.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus
```